# Receber imagens no ASP.Net Core e salvar no Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

Boa tarde,

Alguém sabe me dizer como fazer para receber uma imagem no ASP.Net Core ?

Eu tenho a pagina html que trata de enviar para o servidor:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Produto" asp-action="ImageLoad">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <p>Upload one or more files using this form:</p>
        <input type="file" name="files"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Porem não sei como receber essa imagem no, e salvar ela no banco com o entity.

Acredito que seja algo como :

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task ImageLoad(List<IFormFile> files)
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        // do something
    }
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: Deu certo a reposta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que pude observar o código poderia receber 1 ou várias fotos, mas, no seu `html` faltou declarar isso que é o atributo `multiple` no `input type file`, alteração:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
      asp-controller="Produto" asp-action="ImageLoad">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <p>Upload one or more files using this form:</p>
        <input type="file" name="files" multiple/> // multiple
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Outro porém é quer gravar no banco de dados, seria então gravar o `array de bytes` ou o caminho? Se for o `array de bytes` o código é assim:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task ImageLoad(List<IFormFile> files)
{
    byte[] arq = null;
    foreach (var file in files)
    {           
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
        {
            arq = reader.ReadBytes((int)file.Length);
        }           
        // operações de gravação e utilize
        // a variável file para mandar o valor para o tabela
    }
}
```

agora se for gravar em um diretório é bem parecido só utilizar o valor do file e mandar gravar o caminho na tabela do banco e o arquivo em algum diretório de sua preferencia, exemplo:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task ImageLoad(List<IFormFile> files)
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        file.CopyTo(new FileStream("/diretorio/name_do_arquivo", FileMode.Create));
    }
}
```

Isso são formas reais, mas, genéricas, porque o contexto da pergunta ficou vago, se colocar mais informações eu edito essa parte e coloca a sua realidade, mas, já serve como base.

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [IFormFile Interface](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile?view=aspnetcore-2.0)
- [Classe FileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.90).aspx)
- [IFormFile.CopyTo Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile.copyto?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_IFormFile_CopyTo_System_IO_Stream_)

Comment: Olá Virgilio desculpe a demora para responder, mas então, a resposta do Eduardo, me pareceu melhor em termos de processamento, não sei se estou certo ao dizer isto ...

Eu li um pouco sobre ViewModel e descobri que tem como agilizar a captura dos dados do formulário, porém estou com dificuldades em utilizar em um input file ...

Você é conhecedor do assunto ?

Comment: Olha o que você disse: `Olá Virgilio desculpe a demora para responder, mas então, a resposta do Eduardo, me pareceu melhor em termos de processamento, não sei se estou certo ao dizer isto ..` se não está certo, não pode afirmar inclusive o código que está na minha resposta é o que está na documentação do aspnet core e percebe que é um classe que tem o nome e as características que é para leitura de um dado de array de bytes. Sobre a nova pergunta eu conheço, mas, aqui no Stackoverflow responde uma pergunta, depois se pode fazer outra pergunta e assim por diante a sua duvida tem duas respostas

Comment: ... continuando e você tem que testar as duas formas e creditar e aceitar como resposta alguma delas, após isso você está pronto para perguntar outra pergunta, sobre ViewModel tem vários perguntas e resposta no próprio site, pode ser direcionado a algumas delas ou então feita uma nova se não tiver o mesmo proposito. OK! @John-Jones ...

Comment: Virgilio deu certo com a sua explicação, desculpa a minha falta de conhecimento sobre o assunto, ainda sou novo na programação rs... Obrigado pela paciência e por me ajudar, forte abraço.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Convert IFromFile para base64
  private string ConvertIFromFileToBase64(IFormFile file)
  {
      Stream stream = file.OpenReadStream();
      using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
      {
           stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
           return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
      }
  }
```

agora so salvar no banco normalmente

Comment: E ao invés de eu fazer na classe produto

`public byte[] Photo { get; set; }`

Eu faria algo como 

`public string Photo { get; set; }`

?

Obrigado.